# programmatically sending email using outlook 2013 using bat file

Tags: batch-file, scripting

Im trying to use a bat file to send an email using Outlook 2013, however after running it simply opens an email window and after filling in recipient etc. it stops without sending (image attached). Is the problem due to the script or outlook version? Would it work in outlook 2010?

Here is my bat file:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\OUTLOOK.EXE" /c ipm.note /m "mailto:xxxxxx5@hotmail.com?subject=subject&cc=cc_address&bcc=bcc_address&body=message_body"
```

[image]

Comment: You cannot send with a batch file alone, you need scripting to accomplish that.

Comment: Sorry, won't work as you think it does. You can either create a vba script and use a macro to send it, or use powershell to send using smtp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are using will not work as expected, you need to script it or create some sort of macro using `VBA` or the likes.

**However**, You could just use your powershell's `Send-MailMessage` which comes standard on a windows system by running it in a batchfile:

***NOTE!!** Must be powershell 2.0 or later.*

```
powershell Send-MailMessage 
           -From "someone@someserver.net"
           -To "whoever@gmail.com"
           -Subject "Test email"
           -Body "This is a test"
           -SmtpServer Some_exhange_server_name\
```

I broke down the text using newlines for readability, but it should be a single line.

```
powershell Send-MailMessage -From "someone@someserver.net" -To "whoever@gmail.com" -Subject "Test email" -Body "This is a test" -SmtpServer some_exhange_server_name
```

Alternatively, you could skip batch all together and just create a powershell file called something like `sendmail.ps1` and enter the code

```
Send-MailMessage -From "someone@someserver.net" -To "whoever@gmail.com" -Subject "Test email" -Body "This is a test" -SmtpServer some_exhange_Server_name
```