# Sending an automatic mail with attachment

Tags: powershell, email, batch-file, automation

Everyday at 5 am I will have one .txt log that I want to be sent to one of our representatives. I arrive at the office at 9 am, and at that point it would be to late. It also can't be sent earlier than 4 am, so sending it a day before  is not possible.

Now I researched a bit here and there but couldn't really find anything helpful, I want to make a script (batch, powershell, something like that) which takes a log and send it to mail@address.com everyday. I tried for example smtpsend

```
SMTPSend.exe -fsender@address.com -trecipient@address.com -hexchangeserver.domain.com -sTest -aC:/Logs/testlog.log
```

but it just spewed out this error:

```
Error: Temporary message handling problem [61]
```

Can anyone help me, without writing a whole program? Is this even possible?

Comment: [SO] is a site to **help** users get **their** code running, not to write the code for them. So [edit] the question to contain **your** code in a [mcve].

Comment: @LotPings sorry, my code is kinda the default code of smtpsend, but I will add it if it helps

Comment: Why not use PowerShell [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied code from an earlier answer I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473186/programmatically-sending-email-using-outlook-2013-using-bat-file/47473689#47473689) and ammended it to be used with attachments:

***NOTE!!** Must be powershell 2.0 or later.*

```
powershell Send-MailMessage 
           -From "someone@someserver.net"
           -To "whoever@gmail.com"
           -Subject "Test email"
           -Body "This is a test"
           -SmtpServer Some_exhange_server_name\
           -Attachments "c:\my files\file.log"
```

I broke down the text using newlines for readability, but it should be a single line.

```
powershell Send-MailMessage -From "someone@someserver.net" -To "whoever@gmail.com" -Subject "Test email" -Body "This is a test" -SmtpServer some_exhange_server_name -Attachments "c:\my files\file.log"
```

Alternatively, you could skip batch all together and just create a powershell file called something like `sendmail.ps1` and enter the code

```
Send-MailMessage -From "someone@someserver.net" -To "whoever@gmail.com" -Subject "Test email" -Body "This is a test" -SmtpServer some_exhange_Server_name -Attachments "c:\my files\file.log"
```