# How to move local file to another local folder after sending to mainframe via FTP using batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp, mainframe

I have a local file upload routine, via ftp, to a mainframe using a simple .BAT file, after successfully sending this file it should be moved to another local directory, how can I automate this process? In case of error could just pause script execution

I use two bat files, SEND.BAT and CONFIG.BAT, i run only the SEND.bat;

SEND.bat

```
ftp -s:CONFIG.bat X.X.X.X
pause
```

CONFIG.bat

```
USER
PASSWORD
CD B.A01
put \\SERVER.contoso.com\FOLDER\*.txt RETORNO(+1)
put \\SERVER.contoso.com\FOLDER\*.txt COMPROV(+1)
disconnect
bye
```

After successfully submitting, how could I automatically move these files to a respective local folder in case the mainframe return code is

> 250 send sucessfully

And if the mainframe return is

> Not connected

or

> Failed

just pause the command with `Pause`. Is it possible to send an email warning of both situations or open a website (this website already exists and will call my phone)? Using only bat commands in Windows?

Thanks for help!

Comment: config.bat is not a batch file.  It is an ftp script file. You will need to write a log file of the FTP connection.  Then read the log file for the errors.  Then use an `IF` command based on reading the log file.

Comment: Sorry for mistake, I will try do this! You make my brain think!

Comment: Yeah, brains, thinking is what they are for `:)`

Comment: as for your email query, pure batch? no, incorporating Powershell (which ships by default since Windows 7) then you can look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473186/programmatically-sending-email-using-outlook-2013-using-bat-file/47473689#47473689) which you can stil lincorprate into your batch file